# Creating 3D arcpy.Polyline?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, arcgis-pro

Working with ArcGIS Pro 2.2, I have to create a 3D polyline from array of XYZ coordinates.

When I try this code snippet :

```
array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 0, 0),arcpy.Point(0, 100, -1000)])
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array, has_z=True)
```

I get an error saying that `has_z` is read-only:

```
AttributeError: DescribeGeometry: Read-only attribute has_z
```

From [the docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm) it really does not seem so.

When  I try not to specify the `has_z` parameter:

```
array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 0, 0),arcpy.Point(0, 100, -1000)])
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
```

I receive no errors but the Polyline defaults to `hasz=False` as it has to.

Doing `polyline.firstPoint` confirms this:

```
<Point (0.0, 0.0, #, #)>
```

Is there another legit way to do it?

It seems wrong to me that `has_z` parameter is read-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I made it myself.
I think this is a bug probably.

Using positional parameters rather than name parameters, there's no error.
This is the code I succesfully used to create a 3D polyline, hope it helps.
I'll probably report this to Esri.

```
array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 0, 0),arcpy.Point(0, 100, -1000)])
polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array, None, True)
polyline.firstPoint
>>> <Point (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, #)> #CORRECT!
```

**EDIT**

[Here](https://community.esri.com/message/796646-i-found-many-problems-with-3d-arcpypolylines) is the link to the GeoNet thread I opened.

Comment: I agree its a bug in arcpy shipped with pro v2.50. In arcpy.arcobjects.mixins.py, GeometrySpecializationMixin.__init() first constructs an _arc_object based on positional *args only, and then if any keyword arguments (*kwargs) are present they are added as attributes, but has_z is already set!